# how to convert time() output to a date in php

Tags: php, time

I am using `time()` command in php to store a timestamp value for every time  database is updated i.e whenever a value is updated in database a timestamp is added in a time.

For eg: when a change was made to database yesterday night,  the value added was `1368132319`.

I know the the `time()` commands returns the no of seconds elapsed from jan 1 1970.

Now what i want to do is convert these no of seconds into a user understandable form which can be displayed on an html page. Like these seconds are converted to `date and time`.

How do i do that? i cannot think of a logic to implement it. googled it but to no avail

Comment: $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; echo date($format,$time_in_seconds);

Comment: [Read the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple thing, simply use datetime

```
$date = date_create();
date_timestamp_set($date, 1171502725);
echo date_format($date, 'U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

All in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use below

```
<?
echo date("D-M-Y",$strtime);
?>
```

there are various format available for DATE function in PHP you can use required one.

Comment: Do you always use capital letters for your function calls?

Answer (score 1):

you can see the [demo](http://eval.in/25096) link....

```
<?php
$time_in_seconds = 1368132319;
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; 
echo date($format,$time_in_seconds);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [date()](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.date.php) function. Example:

```
$timestamp = 1368132319; // in your case the value from the DB
echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp); // 2013-05-09
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); // 2013-05-09 23:45:19
```